# Shield arduino for electrical interference

Tags: arduino, relay, interference

I have an Arduino UNO controlling two high voltage relays via a switch. It also reads out a third relay, which is controlled outside of the Arduino. My setup looks like this:
[image: Circuit setup]

With the following representing circuit:
[image]

When I turn on the soldering station, the Arduino reads an interrupt on pin 2, where the switch is connected. This also happens when the 12V source is replaced by a car battery. The soldering station is also not grounded. Due to these facts I concluded it must be some kind of electrical interference, probably EMI. I have been looking all over the web to find a way to isolate the Arduino from the interference but I can't find a proper way.

Does anyone know how to shield the Arduino for the interference?

Thanks on forehand.

Comment: Where are your flyback diodes?

Comment: They are inside the relays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do several things to reduce the effects of interference on the pin2 input. There is no one answer of how to prevent EMI causing problems, each system is different and each system needs a different solution. But here's some general tips for you to try:

1. **Reduce interference at the source.** This is the best, but it's not always possible.  You could check that the switch on the solder station isn't too worn, but you're probably not going to gain anything here.  I've written it anyway, because it's a good general rule.
2. **Reduce R1**. Smaller pull-down resistors mean more current available and less susceptibility to EMI. If you were using 100k, I would definitely suggest a smaller value, but you might still see some gain from going below 10K.
3. **Filter/debounce.** The usual approach to debouncing switches, with a capacitor, can help reject brief transient EMI. It's also generally a good idea.
4. **Sheilding**.  Put everything inside a metal enclosure, and connect the enclosure to ground.
5. **Wiring**. Avoid long lengths of wire, and especially avoid long lengths of wire outside the enclosure. Where long wires are unavoidable, group them together to reduce loop area. If S1 needs to be outside the box, connect it using twisted pair (or even better, shielded twisted pair). Connect the shield to the enclosure.

Comment: I have tried Reducing R1 and debouncing the switch, both in hardware and software, neither worked. The wiring will eventually be less of a problem since the whole circuit will end up on a custom PCB board, which also makes shielding a lot easier. Reducing interference at the source isn't an option since the eventual interference source will be an electric motor, the soldering station just showed me it is sensitive for the interference. Nonetheless, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Two other options that might be worth a try are:

1. Checking to see if an optocoupler might solve the problem. I have used these before on circuits interfacing with high voltage devices and they provide decent isolation physically, if that ends up being the real problem here.
2. Instead of having the pull down configuration that R1 is in right now perhaps switch it to a pull up. You would need to reconfigure how your device detects interrupts, but interference might not trigger the ISR in this case since your Arduino is waiting for that pin to go to GND.

Good luck!